# Move a child array to parent array and change parent/child name

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, foreach

I know probably this was asked before not sure if was in this form but I did tried some replay from what I found here about this and failed.

ok I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Data3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [category] => Whiskey
                    [name] => Some name
                    [description] => description
                    [image] => asdf.jpg
                    [price] => 83.99
                )

            [ammount] => 1
            [Data_id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Data3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [category] => Tequila
                    [name] => Something Red 75cl
                    [description] => description
                    [image] => sierratequilasilver100.jpg
                    [price] => 92.49
                )

            [ammount] => 2
            [Data_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Data4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category] => Whiskey
                    [name] => Some name Gold
                    [description] => description
                    [image] => asdf.jpg
                    [price] => 83.99
                )

            [ammount] => 1
            [Data_id] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Data4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [category] => Vodka
                    [name] => Something Blue 100 cl
                    [description] => description
                    [image] => Something.jpg
                    [price] => 32.44
                )

            [ammount] => 1
            [Data_id] => 4
        )

)
```

What I would like to be the result is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [category] => Whiskey
            [name] => Some name
            [description] => description
            [image] => asdf.jpg
            [price] => 83.99
            [ammount] => 1
            [Data_id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [category] => Tequila
            [name] => Something Red 75cl
            [description] => description
            [image] => sierratequilasilver100.jpg
            [price] => 92.49
            [ammount] => 2
            [Data_id] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [category] => Whiskey
            [name] => Some name Gold
            [description] => description
            [image] => asdf.jpg
            [price] => 83.99
            [ammount] => 1
            [Data_id] => 4
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [category] => Vodka
            [name] => Something Blue 100 cl
            [description] => description
            [image] => Something.jpg
            [price] => 32.44
            [ammount] => 1
            [Data_id] => 4
        )
)
```

or another way I could work with is if I can change **Data1, Data2, Data3** and so on ..

> can be n Data depends how many producs a user select

into a same name ex simple **Data** or **Info**.

ex:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Info] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [category] => Whiskey
                    [name] => Some name
                    [description] => description
                    [image] => asdf.jpg
                    [price] => 83.99
                )

            [ammount] => 1
            [Data_id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Info] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [category] => Tequila
                    [name] => Something Red 75cl
                    [description] => description
                    [image] => sierratequilasilver100.jpg
                    [price] => 92.49
                )

            [ammount] => 2
            [Data_id] => 3
        )
```

Any solution will be fine for me.

Thanks and regards

Comment: why is that data stored in that structure to start with? If you are building the array you could do it at that point as it'll prevent you rebuilding it

Comment: The data is there as each array is a sql request from different tables. ex data3 is from table3 and so on.

Comment: then you need to change your sql so it retrieves all the info correctly. Look at SQL JOINS. If any of the answers here solve your issue please mark as correct and open a new question if required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for your result:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $offset1 => $array2) {

    $tmp_array = array();

    foreach($array2 as $offset2 =>  $array3) {

        if(is_array($array3)) {
            $tmp_array = $array3;
        } else {
            $tmp_array[$offset2] = $array3
        }

    }

    $final_array = array_merge($final_array, $tmp_array;); 
    //or
    $final_array[] = $tmp_array;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your first option:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        foreach($value as $k => $val){
            if(is_array($val)){                    
                $arr[$key] = $val;
                unset($arr[$key][$k]);
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);
```

[Check output here](https://3v4l.org/0HJ3E)

Comment: Worked for example but after some more tests it does not show my amount and data_id for more values.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this this way. However I would look to fix why the data is in that structure to begin with.

```
$aStartArray =  array(array('Data3'=>array('id'=>1, 'cat'=>2), 'amount' => 1, 'Data_id'=>3));

foreach ($aStartArray as $iPos => $aArray) {

    $aKeys = array_keys($aArray); // fetches all the keys
    $aFirstElement = $aArray[$aKeys[0]]; // Get the first element using first key

    // assign/ overwrite data at the same position
    $aStartArray[$iPos] = array($aFirstElement, 'amount' => $aArray['amount'], 'Data_id' => $aArray['Data_id']);
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($aStartArray);
```

Comment: This work to in my example but my vars are dynamically. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best algorithm

```js
const moveArrayToParentArray = (input) => {
  let finalOutput = []

  input.forEach((e) => {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      finalOutput = [...finalOutput, ...e];

    } else {
      finalOutput = [...finalOutput, e];
    }

  })

  return finalOutput
}

const array = ['a', 'b']
const array2 = [array]
const array3 = [array, "c"]

console.log(moveArrayToParentArray(array))
console.log("----------------------------")

console.log(moveArrayToParentArray(array2))
console.log("----------------------------")

console.log(moveArrayToParentArray(array3))
console.log("----------------------------")
```

Comment: This is JS. The OP ask about PHP.